# Separate Users accounts

Tags: python, django, object

I want to separate the open sessions in my site so a user can't delete/modify objects from another account. If someone could explain me how do I do that, for example here with the delete function.
This is my code:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser): ##abstract user model
    pass

class Auction(models.Model): ##these are the objects
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='listing_image', null=True, default="/static/default_image.jpg")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    starting_bid = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auctions", null=True)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def delete(request, id):
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        auction.delete()
        return redirect ('index')
    return render(request, "auctions/delete.html", {
        "auction": auction
    })
```

html:

```
 {{auction.user}}
    <h1>{{ auction.name }}</h1>
    <img src="{{ auction.img.url }}" width="600"> 
            <h5>Starting price: ${{ auction.starting_bid }}</h5>
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {%csrf_token%}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place a New Bid</button>
                {{form.as_p}}
            </form>
            {%for bid in bids%}
            <h3>${{ bid.new_bid}}</h3>
            {%empty%}
            No offers yet.
            {%endfor%}
            {{auction.description}}
          
        <h2>Comments</h2>
    <ul>
        <p><a href="{% url 'new_comment' auction.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary">New Comment</a></p>

        {%for comment in comments%}
            <li>{{comment.user}} - {{comment.created_on}}
                <p><h4>{{comment.body}}</h4></p>              
            </li>
        {%empty%}
            <li>No comments yet.</li>
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
    <p><a href="{% url 'edit' auction.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'delete' auction.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You filter on the user as well:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def delete(request, id):
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, id=id, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auction.delete()
        return redirect ('index')
    return render(request, 'auctions/delete.html', {
        'auction': auction
    })
```

This will return a HTTP 404 error in case the `.user` of the `Auction` is not the logged in user, so they will not be able to remove the object.

In the template, you need to check if the user is the logged in one to show the buttons. But even if you somehow show buttons, the users will not be able to trigger the logic behnind it if you filter accordingly:

```
{% if user == auction.user %}
<p><a href="{% url 'edit' auction.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
<a href="{% url 'delete' auction.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</a></p>
{% endif %}
```